# Mail server or private or public lan?

Tags: email-server, local-area-network, private

I've currently got only one server running Webserver,DB server and Mail server and I want to distribute the services in 3 servers to reduce the strain put on that single server. I've got to NICs on each server so I'm planning on using 2 LANs to provide an extra layer of security. On the private network(the one used only by these computers) I'm going to connect the DB Server, an additional backup server and one of the NICs of the Web server. On the public network(the one connected to the Internet) I'm going to connect the other NIC of the Web server. I have no idea however on which network to connect the Mail server. Does it need to be directly connected to the Internet or does the traffic flow through the Web server?

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mail traffic (SMTP) does not flow via webpages. If you want to be able to receive mail on the mail server then it needs to be reachable via the internet. Same for sending mail to the outside world.

If you only use it for internal mails then by all means, put it safely on the private net.

Comment: When put like this it really makes sense. Silly me. Thanks a million. I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.